# Component life-cycle

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to understand the issue in the ember-form-for (https://github.com/martndemus/ember-form-for/blob/master/addon/components/form-field.js#L64) but IMHO the code is not that important, it is just an ordinary component.

The component works perfectly when re-rendering does not occur. In the *init()* we will do *set(this, 'name', 'value')* and it works as expected. But after re-rendering, the *init()* is not called as expected (https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/), the object has same identifier as before rendering but the value that were set in the *init()* are lost. And I do not understand why.

Comment: what do you mean by `re-rendering`?

Comment: init() is not called on re-render and that is what I get from reading the docs. init() is only called on initial render. Perhaps you can declare your properties outside of init() instead.

Comment: @Loopo but in re-rendering the component is not destroyed so it should not lose the state. or should it?

Comment: @SteveH. For example, after attributes of a component have changed. In case of this component, the errors were detected in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
[
  'inputClasses',
  ...
].forEach((type) => {
  set(this, type, (get(this, type) || []).concat(get(this, `config.${type}`)));
});
```

The problem is that instance variables are not a good solution. *inputClasses* (and others) are used also as attributes for the component. It means that after re-render they are overwritten by original value (and .concat is not used). I'm aware of two solutions:

- If we will change the name of the internal variables to NOT match the input attributes, we are fine.
- The nice solution is to use computed properties.

Answer (score 0):

In the [ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_formatting-component-attributes-with-code-didreceiveattrs-code) we learn that there is a lifecycle hook that will get called on rerender as well, the `didReceiveAttrs` hook.

So, use this and your component will change the state accordingly to the changed attributes.